# Error when creating animation in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

New to XAML... i want to do some simple animations. I was trying to follow MSDN's example code from this link: [Click Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.elasticease%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimation
          Storyboard.TargetName="MyAnimatedRectangle"
          Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
          From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" 
          AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <Rectangle Loaded="Start_Animation" x:Name="MyAnimatedRectangle"
     Width="100" Height="100" Fill="Blue" />

</StackPanel>
```

I keep getting this error: "All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute associated with them. Line 11 Position 18"

What does this error mean? How do i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `StackPanel` as every `FrameworkElement` has a property `Recources` which is a [ResourceDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.aspx) and you can only add elements to there with the `x:Key` attribute to identify them (basically this a `IDictioanry<string, object>`). So you need to add a `x:Key` to your storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboard" x:Key="myStoryboardKey">
```

The sample on MSDN is wrong or they meant `x:Key="myStoryboard"` instead of `x:Name="myStoryboard"`.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `x:Name="myStoryboard"` with `x:Key="myStoryboard"` should be enough to fix this issue.

The reason you need a `Key` in this case is because the code-behind is using a `IDictionary`, which requires an unique key for identification.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx